# How to install a complete version of Eclipse?

Tags: installation, eclipse

I am looking into installing Eclipse but I'm having a slight difficulty. Unlike Visual Studio eclipse needs some very odd addons and things that are on their website. Is there just a complete version where I can get everything immediately? I don't want to just keep installing these things in case I need them I just want them all there.

Comment: Looking at the eclipse downloads page.. Are you sure they are extensions and non-contradictory. Like, maybe Eclipse for java is a different Eclipse to eclipse for C. So, what I mean is , if you install both, perhaps they might be two separate eclipse installations, one configured for java, one configured for C. So, perhaps they're not like addons/extensions/plugins. Have you checked?  On the website it calls each one a "package". I suggest checking as maybe they're not extensions as you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you download an Eclipse package, say Eclipse for Java or Eclipse for C++, you're simply downloading the base platform with a language specific *perspective* or set of plugins. Irrespective of which package you downloaded you can always follow the instructions [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-124.htm) to install new software.

Just go to `Help / Install New Software`, select or specify the proper software repository URL for your version (for example, Juno's repository is at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/), then check the *Programming Languages* section and install [JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/), [CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) etc.

I don't think there's one huge combined download available, but once you've downloaded everything you need you can simply carry the main folder and your workspace around, since the app's pretty much [portable](https://superuser.com/questions/163957/is-eclipse-installation-portable) in nature (might need to adjust some paths, especially for Java VM or external tools though).

Comment: Well I guess that's my best option. Thanks for the help.