# Portable Eclipse Error

Tags: java, eclipse

As a side-project I am trying to create myself a portable eclipse installation. The drive I use is the Samsung T5 500GB SSD.
Before starting with this I searched through the web and found this helpful [link](https://superuser.com/questions/163957/is-eclipse-installation-portable). I completed the instructions given "Mokubai" in their post. I used the jre1.8.0_211, which I copied from the directory on my computer. I run the .exe and specified the workspace to ".\Workspace".

1. Runs smoothly on my own computer.
2. Doesn't run on my testing computer. Following is the error message I get:
   [Eclipse; Java was started but returned exit code=13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94FVZ.png)

I have googled the error to find out more about what and why it's caused.
With the help of this [link](https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/06/java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code13.html) and a thorough re-read of the error, I think the destination of "javaw.exe" is wrongly specified.

With the help of this [link](https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/06/java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code13.html) I tried to manually specify the destination to said .exe. Here is the [link](https://pastebin.com/VGAqb1ij) to my "eclipse.ini"-file.

I tested it with the modified .ini, yet I still get the same error as linked earlier this post.

Does somebody have a solution/fix for this error?

---

EDIT:

I checked whether my computers I try to start eclipse with are 32 bit or 64 bit. Without any doubt I can say that they are 64 bit (OS: Win10 Home & Win10 Enterprise). The eclipse installation on my external SSD is 64 bit too. If I had a 32bit Eclipse it shouldn't even run if I understood @greg-449's comment correctly. Funnily enough I can run Eclipse on my company's notebook (64bit Win10 Enterprise) without any problem.  When I try to run it on any other computer I will get the linked error.

---

TL;DR: My portable ecplipse returns Error:13 when executed and has (presumbaly) the wrong path specified for the "javaw.exe". I tried setting the path via an argument in the "eclipse.ini"-file.

Comment: Error 13 generally means you are trying to run a 32 bit Eclipse on a 64 bit Java (or the other way round). Eclipse and Java must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit. Note that recent releases of Eclipse are 64 bit only and won't run on 32 bit machine.

Comment: I checked whether my computers I try to start eclipse with are 32 bit or 64 bit. Without any doubt I can say that they are 64 bit (OS: Win10 Home & Win10 Enterprise). The eclipse installation on my external SSD is 64 bit too. If I had a 32bit Eclipse it shouldn't even run if I understood @greg-449's comment correctly. Funnily enough I can run Eclipse on my company's notebook (64bit Win10 Enterprise) without any problem. When I try to run it on any other computer I will get the linked error.

Added this edit to the original post :)

Comment: It is possible to have a 32 bit Java installed on a 64 bit machine - you must check that the Java installation is also 64 bit.